# Printing valid combination of parentheses in python

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to print all valid combination of parentheses in python using my own intuition. It almost worked but just that it doesn't print few combinations. The code looks like this

```
solution = ""

def parentheses(n):

    global solution

    if n == 0:
        print solution
        return

    for i in range(1, n+1):
        start_index = len(solution)
        solution = solution + ( "(" * i + ")" * i )
        parentheses(n - i)
        solution = solution[:start_index]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = int(raw_input("Enter the number of parentheses:"))
    print "The possible ways to print these parentheses are ...."
    parentheses(n)
```

For n = 3, it prints

( )( )( ) 
( )( ( ) ) 
( ( ) )( )
( ( (  ) ) )

It works like this.

In the first iteration

( )( )( ) will be printed, when the call returns to the immediate parent, it will slice of the list where it started to append first which will now be ( ) and run the next iteration of the loop to print ( )( ( ) ) and so on

The problem is I am somehow not able to capture this combination using this logic

( ( )( ) )

While I am thinking on how to fix it, if any python guru can suggest a fix to this, then that will be great. There are alternate solutions, but since I came very close, I want to improve mine.

Comment: I don't think that any straightforward modification of this will work since you are trying to reduce parentheses(n) to strings obtained by single calls to parentheses(k) (where k < n). Surely parentheses(10) requires  elements of parentheses(6) concatenated with elements of parenthesis(4) -- but the way that you are using a single global value rather than return values would seem to preclude the simultaneous existence of the strings in parentheses(6) and the strings in parentheses(4)

Comment: Spot on, it's not introspecting deep enough as highlighted by your 6 - 4 example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your current version of the logic is a little oversimplified to capture all the possibilities.

This problem boils down to 3 different cases:

1. We've used all of our open parentheses and just need to close them
2. We don't have any currently open parentheses and need to add one before closing again
3. We've got at least one open and can either open a new one or close one.

To follow that logic, we then need to keep track of the number of open parens we have left to use (`no` below), the current string of parens, and the current balance of open vs. closed (`curb` below):

```
def parens(no, s="", curb=0):
    # case 1: all open parens used
    if no == 0: 
        if curb == 0: 
            return [s]
        return parens(no, s+")", curb-1) 

    # case 2: none are currently open
    if curb == 0:
        return parens(no-1, s+"(", curb+1)

    # case 3: one or more are currently open
    return parens(no-1, s+"(", curb+1) + parens(no, s+")", curb-1)
```

Comment: Well explained, I always try to simplify recursion but this three way approach is something I will keep in mind to solve similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a natural use of [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). `parenthesis(10)` will involve `parentheses(6)` and `parentheses(4)`, but `parentheses(9)` will *also* involve `parentheses(6)` -- so `parenthesis(6)` should just be computed once. Also -- it is natural to use sets since that prevents e.g. `()()()` from being counted twice, once as `() + ()()` and once as `()() + ()`. This leads to the following code, which either slaps a new pair of parentheses around parentheses generated for `n-1` or concatenates the results of two previous calls:

```
cache = {}

def parentheses(n):
    if n == 0:
        return set([''])
    elif n in cache:
        return cache[n]
    else:
        par = set('(' + p + ')' for p in parentheses(n-1))
        for k in range(1,n):
            par.update(p+q for p in parentheses(k) for q in parentheses(n-k))
        cache[n] = par
        return par
```

For example,

```
>>> for p in parentheses(3): print(p)

(()())
((()))
()(())
()()()
(())()
```